# How to do a Translate Animation for both axis(X, Y) at the same time?

Tags: windows-phone-7, animation, windows-phone-7.1

I am doing something like this in my Storyboard method but not able to achieve the desired result. This animation I want to be played after the page is loaded.

```
    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CreateTranslateAnimation(image1);
    }


        private void CreateTranslateAnimation(UIElement source)
        {
            Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();

            DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames animationFirstX = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
            source.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform();
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animationFirstX, new PropertyPath(CompositeTransform.TranslateXProperty));
            Storyboard.SetTarget(animationFirstX, source.RenderTransform);
            animationFirstX.KeyFrames.Add(new EasingDoubleKeyFrame() { KeyTime = kt1, Value = 20 });

            DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames animationFirstY = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
            source.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform();
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animationFirstY, new PropertyPath(CompositeTransform.TranslateYProperty));
            Storyboard.SetTarget(animationFirstY, source.RenderTransform);
            animationFirstY.KeyFrames.Add(new EasingDoubleKeyFrame() { KeyTime = kt1, Value = 30 });

    sb.Children.Add(animationFirstX);
            sb.Children.Add(animationFirstY);
            sb.Begin();             
         }
```

To cut it short...

I want to write .cs code equivalent to this code

```
    <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="image1">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="20"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="image1">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="30"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
```

Comment: What does this do that isn't what you want? Please provide a complete example which shows how you're using this code.

Comment: This is just moving the image along the y-axis and what I required 
while writing this code was to move it along both the axis like in a diag. fashion, say from (0,0) to (20,30) which are the co-ords. given in 

animationFirstX.KeyFrames.Add(new EasingDoubleKeyFrame() { KeyTime = kt1, Value = 20 } 
animationFirstY.KeyFrames.Add(new EasingDoubleKeyFrame() { KeyTime = kt1, Value = 30 } 

these lines(see the code).

Comment: You could also define your animation in xaml an then access it your code behind and alter the it's props during the runtime.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the `source.RenderTransform` twice. The first transform animation is referencing a CompositeTransform object *that has been removed from the UIElement when the animation runs*.

Get rid of the second `source.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform();` and you should get better results.

*"Cut & paste is the source is the source of much coding evil"* :)